# Using reactiveValues list to produce to produce dataframe with vector names - R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a dynamic reactiveValues list of vectors and want to get a dataframe with the column names of the names of the vector out.

In my case the names of the vector are generated by the user and could change

```
e.g.

data<-reactiveValues()

vector1<-c("a", "b)
names(vector1)<-"test1"

vector2<-c("a", "b)
names(vector2)<-"test2"

data[[paste0(1)]]<-vector1
data[[paste0(2)]]<-vector2


bind_cols(data)
```

This results in a very ugly object where the column names are "1" and "2" (inspected using isolate(reactiveValuesToList(data)) )

The names of the vector are buried in the attributes

if only data is returned (and not bind_cols(data)) then `` attributes(data[[`1`]])$dimnames[[2]] `` will return the name of the vector.

How can I get round this issue?

Edit:

Was being an idiot. What I really wanted was to return a  1 column data frame. Names of a vector arent the same as colnames of a dataframe. Names of a vector are on a row basis.

Comment: Could you indicate what would be the correct output? I don't understand if you want to have "test1" and "test2" as column names, or "a" and "b".

Comment: @Tomas Capretto the desired outcome is to have the column names the same.as.the vector name (i.e. test1 ect)

Comment: Couldn't you just use `data[[names(vector1)[1]]] <- vector1`? (and please note that you mix up the vector name and the names of the elements of the vector: e.g. in `vector1 <- c("a", "b")`; names(vector1)  <- c("name1", "name2")` the name of the vector is "vector1" and the names of the elements are "name1" and "name2")

Comment: @starja I guess what i am really trying to do is either get a reactiveValue where i can subset it with an integer like you would do a normal list or rename the names in reactiveValues

Comment: I think then the easiest way is to use `reactiveValuesToList`. You get a normal list that you can subset with an integer. Does this help? Otherwise you could update the question with your core problem

Answer (score 0):

Two (similar) alternatives come to my mind

The first one is doing everything as you do, adding two lines of code

```r
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

isolate({
  data <- reactiveValues()
  
  vector1 <- c("a", "b")
  names(vector1) <- "test1"
  
  vector2 <- c("a", "b")
  names(vector2) <- "test2"
  
  data[[paste0(1)]] <- vector1
  data[[paste0(2)]] <- vector2
  
  l = reactiveValuesToList(data)
  df = bind_cols(l)
  colnames(df) = vapply(l, function(x) unique(na.omit(names(x))), FUN.VALUE = character(1))
})
```

I would convert `data` reactiveValues to a list, then use `bind_cols()` with the list, and then obtain column names by getting the names of the vectors within the list `l`. Here you have to use `na.omit()` function because when you do

```r
  vector1 <- c("a", "b")
  names(vector1) <- "test1"
```

only the first element has the name "test1", the other is `NA`.

The second alternative is the same, but assigning the name "test1" to all the elements in `vector1`

```r
  vector1 <- c("a", "b")
  names(vector1) <- rep("test1", length(vector1))
```

but it feels weird to have all the elements in a vector with the same name.
Then, you would do the same, without the `na.omit()` function.

If this does not satisfy the requirements of your app, please share more details of your app and I will try to help you.